# C++11 rvalue reference and const-ness

Tags: c++11, rvalue-reference

The following code is a snippet of a tuple-like class where it is possible to get a reference to a given type in the tuple, or if that type is not found, the provided default value will be returned instead.

If the default value is a lvalue a reference must be returned, if the default value is a rvalue then a rvalue must be returned.

The following code illustrates the problem I'm having:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(int d) : data(d) {}

    template <typename T, typename TT>
    const TT get_or_default(TT&& t) const {
        return data;
    }

    template <typename T, typename TT>
    TT get_or_default(TT&& t) {
        return data;
    }

    int data;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int i = 6;
    const Foo foo1(5);
    Foo foo2(5);

    // compile error
    foo1.get_or_default<int>(i);

    // works
    foo1.get_or_default<int>(5);
    foo2.get_or_default<int>(i) = 4;
    foo2.get_or_default<char>('a');

    return 0;
}
```

When compiling this I get the following error:

```
cxx.cxx:6:20: error: binding of reference to type 'int' to a value of type 'const int' drops qualifiers
            return data;
                   ^~~~
cxx.cxx:23:14: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Foo::get_or_default<int, int &>' requested here
        foo1.get_or_default<int>(i);
             ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: `foo.get_or_default<int>(i);` foo is not declared...

Comment: Ups this is a type, now fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a special rule for template argument deduction when the function parameter is of type `T&&` where `T` is a template parameter. That rule is:

> If the function argument is an lvalue of type `U`, then `U&` is used in place of `U` for type deduction in this case.

It's used to allow perfect forwarding. Basically, it means that `T&&` for a template parameter `T` is a "universal reference."

In your case, since `i` is indeed an lvalue, `TT` is deduced to `int&`. Applying a `const` to that is ignored (it would apply to the reference itself, not to the type referred to), so the fucntion instantiated from the template looks something like this:

```
int& get_or_default(int& t) const {
  return data;
}
```

And since the function is `const`, `data` is considered `const` as well and so it cannot bind to a non-const reference.

Comment: The prototype looks like this: `const TT get_or_default(TT&& t) const` you deleted the const-ness of the return type.

Comment: @Allan I did not, and the answer addresses it. Re-read this: "`TT` is deduced to `int&`. **Applying a `const` to that is ignored** (it would apply to the reference itself, not to the type referred to)." When you type `const int &`, it means "reference to constant `int`." When you type `const TT`, where `TT` is `int&`, it means "constant `TT`", i.e. something like "constant reference to `int`," which is really the same as "reference to `int`."

Comment: I see your point - sorry about the comment. But could you please suggest how I can work around this? It is important that a reference it returned when a lvalue is provided. I found a solution which includes writing my own add_cost helper class and use this to alter the return type, but I'm not sure if this is the right way of doing it (std::add_const will not add const to references).

Comment: @Allan I believe a custom type trait to keep `int` an `int` but turn `int&` into `const int&` is the way to go - there's nothing in the standard library that could do it for you.